# How to create extension for all types that have ".contains"?

Tags: swift, swift-extensions, swift2

I'd like to create an extension off all types that have the `.contains` API.

For example, I did this for strings, but would like to expand it for all types:

```
func within(values: [String]) -> Bool {
    return values.contains(self)
}
```

With this, instead of this:

`["abc", "def", "ghi"].contains("def")`

I can do this for convenience:

`"def".within(["abc", "def", "ghi"])`

But I'd like to work with anything like this for example:

`[.North, .South].contains(.West)`

So I can do this with enums:

```
let value = .West
value.within([.North, .South])
```

Is creating a broad extension possible for this scenario?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[That version of the `contains` method](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/protocol/SequenceType/#comment-func-generator-element_-equatable-contains_) is defined for any `SequenceType` whose members are `Equatable`. So what you want is to extend `Equatable`. Like this:

```
extension Equatable {
    func within<Seq: SequenceType where Seq.Generator.Element == Self> (values: Seq) -> Bool {
        return values.contains(self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer!  I was trying to extend `GeneratorType`, but this is definitely a better approach.